# Why my variables are not changing ? Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                 

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'
Bokoblin_HP=30
Bokoblin_STR=5
Link_HP=60
Link_STR=10

while [ $Bokoblin_HP -ne 0 ]
      echo "Bokblin HP : ${Bokoblin_HP}/30"
do
    read -p "Press A to Attack or Press H to Heal : " action
    if [ $action = "A" ]
    then
        ((Bokoblin_HP=$Bokoblin_HP-$Link_STR))
        echo $Bokoblin_HP
    fi
done
```

Result :

```
Bokoblin HP : 30/30
Press A to Attack or Press H to Heal : A
30
```

I'm doing an operation on Bokoblin_HP and I would like to stop the program when it reach 0, but my variable won't change and still 30.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`? A shell like `dash` will treat `((...))` as a nested sub shell, not an arithmetic command. Try `Bokoblin_HP=$((Bokoblin_HP - Link_STR))` instead.

Comment: @chepner Dash would also complain about `read -p`. The echo in the while condition _is_ the culprit, try it.

Comment: I agree the echo is *a* problem, but that doesn't explain why `echo $Bokoblin_HP` continues to output `30` after the supposed update. Good point about `read -P`.

Comment: (Unless that's a typo in the question.)

Comment: How are you actually running the script?

Answer (score 1):

Just swap two lines make the program work.

**Also, be sure to type an upper `A`**

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                 

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'
Bokoblin_HP=30
Bokoblin_STR=5
Link_HP=60
Link_STR=10

while [ $Bokoblin_HP -ne 0 ]
do
    echo "Bokblin HP : ${Bokoblin_HP}/30"
    read -p "Press A to Attack or Press H to Heal : " action
    if [ $action = "A" ]
    then
        ((Bokoblin_HP=$Bokoblin_HP-$Link_STR))
        echo $Bokoblin_HP
    fi
done
```

Output :

```
<user>@<machine> ~
└─ $ ./test.sh 
Bokblin HP : 30/30
Press A to Attack or Press H to Heal : A
20
Bokblin HP : 20/30
Press A to Attack or Press H to Heal : A
10
Bokblin HP : 10/30
Press A to Attack or Press H to Heal : A
0
<user>@<machine> ~
```

Comment: The location of the `echo` statement is legal and not the problem.

Comment: @chepner The `echo` statement makes the condition for `while` always return true, no?

Comment: @chepner I didn't say that it was not legal.

Comment: @BenjaminW. exactly . Legal but buggy. I think the main problem of OP is that he is trying with a `a` instead of `A`

Comment: Ah, true, although the output suggests the problem is that the variable is never updated, not that the loop condition fails to be false. (You can simply swap the order of the `echo` and `[...]`, though.)

Comment: True, the output shown doesn't seem to be correct for an input of actually `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Idk how is supposed to work your solution, im using this

`Bokoblin_HP=$(($Bokoblin_HP-$Link_STR))`

Comment: No, that makes no difference.

Comment: It works for me, i tested it with your code. Also I was confused for a while, because I was pressing "a", it wants big A with shift, are you pressing shift?

Comment: @KheopsHD Please accept the answer if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @Huholoman could you explain why  `((Bokoblin_HP=$Bokoblin_HP-$Link_STR))` does not work and `Bokoblin_HP=$(($Bokoblin_HP-$Link_STR))` does ?

Comment: @CorentinLimier Because the OP is almost certainly not actually using `bash`. `((...))` is setting `Bokoblin_HP` to the literal string `30-10` in a subshell, and after that subshell exits, the value of `Bokoblin_HP` is still 30. No arithmetic is being performed in the current shell. `$((...))`, on the other hand, is a POSIX-compliant features supported by a broader range of shells. (Although I don't know what shell would support `read -p` like `bash` does but not have `((...))` as an arithmetic command.)

Comment: @Huholoman you can add chepner explanation then on your answer

Comment: @CorentinLimier My solution is arithmetic expansion http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html

I never saw the solution in origin code, so I dont know, why it didnt work.